# Honda Civic Hybrid: IMA Battery and egg-like smell

Tags: honda, battery, civic, smell, hybrid

My 2008 Honda Civic Hybrid won't start.
When I try to turn on the engine, the lights in the dashboard flash but nothing happens. I've jumped the car several times and have finally accepted that the battery's dead. However, the IMA warning light did not turn on between the jumps at all.
Something else I've been seeing is smoke from the battery region under the hood.
Also, my car has been emitting this egg-like smell from the vents here and there. Does this have anything to do with the battery?
If I do need a new battery, how and where can I get it?
Thank you in advance from a poor college student!

Comment: The smell is battery out-gassing. It's emitting hydrogen sulfide (H2S).  If it is persistent then likely do to over charging.   The smoke in the battery region is a bigger concern.  Have you looked in that area and seen any burnt looking items?  Or could you see what exactly was smoking (contacts, wires, battery).

Answer (score 2):

You can be pretty sure this is an issue with your battery. Remember (as you probably already know), there are two batteries on most hybrids: a 12vdc battery to start the vehicle and run the electronics; the storage battery which provides for the hybrid effect. As @spicetraders stated, the rotten egg smell is hydrogen sulfide gas emissions. The only place for this to come from on your car is the 12vdc battery. This and all the other things you've stated would lead me to believe the battery is done. It may be low on electrolyte, which *might* solve your issues if you refilled with distilled water, but chances are you are way beyond this point.

To that end, take your battery out of the Civic and bring it to your favorite parts dealer. They'll be able to tell you the state of the battery by testing it. They should have a battery replacement for you on hand, as the battery in question is just a typical lead acid battery ... you just need the right size to fix the issue.

NOTE: Be careful of the battery. If the acid inside spills on you, you can be burned. Just keep the battery upright and you should be just fine.